# Download images from s3 bucket using Promise in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, promise

I want to download some image files from s3 bucket on my local system using Promises in node.js.

```
var params = {
    Bucket: bucket_name',
    Key: 'key'
};

var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/file.jpg');
```

I tried this which is working

```
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream.pipe(fileStream);
```

But I want my code look like this

```
return s3.getObject(params).promise()
    .then(function(data) {
        //console.log(data.Body);
        // No idea about this section
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
```

I have to use Promise to ensure all images should be downloaded.

Comment: You can use any promise library to wrap s3 code into  a promise (like bluebird). I don't think you would be able to use streaming with it, though

Comment: but i have to stream it to create a file with that

Comment: You can save it to the file without a stream as S3 can return just a byte array which you will save into the file

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to use `bluebird` and create a function that returns a promise on the end of the stream:

```
const B = require('bluebird');

function downloadFromS3 (object) {
    var p = B.Promise.defer();

    var stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()

    stream.pipe(fileStream);

    stream.on('error', (e) => p.reject(e))

    stream.on('end', () => p.resolve())

    return p.promise;
}

downloadFromS3(params)
    .then(() => console.log('finished'))
    .catch(() => console.log('failed'))
```

Not sure if this code specifically would work, but it may give you a direction to look into.

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet worked for me;

```
async function getObjectStreamSync(params, dest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // create read stream for object
        let stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

        var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
        stream.pipe(fileStream);

        // on error reject the Promise
        stream.on('error', (err) => reject(new Error(err)));

        // on end resolve the Promise
        stream.on('end', () => resolve());
    });
}

await getObjectStreamSync(params, "path/to/file/file.ext");
```

Here, wrapped the stream within Promise. And by listening to the emitted events reject/resolve the Promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
streamToPromise = require('stream-to-promise');

var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/file.jpg');
streamToPromise(fileStream).then(function () {
  console.log('Image saved to file.');
});
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream.pipe(fileStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a native promise solution with error detection on the read stream and on the write stream.

```
function streamPromise(stream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('end', () => {
            resolve('end');
        });
        stream.on('finish', () => {
            resolve('finish');
        });
        stream.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}

async function s3Download(srcBucket, srcKey, outputPath) {
    var objReq = s3.getObject({
        Bucket: srcBucket,
        Key: srcKey
    });
    let outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
    let readStream = objReq.createReadStream();
    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.warn('s3download error', err);
        outStream.emit("error", err);
    });
    readStream.pipe(outStream);
    return streamPromise(outStream);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a snippet to use async/await with NodeJS 8:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const decompress = require('decompress');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const s3Params = {
  Bucket: s3Location.bucketName,
  Key: s3Location.objectKey,
};
const s3Object = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();
await fs.writeFile('myfile.zip', s3Object.Body);
await decompress('myfile.zip', 'myFileDir');

/* The compressed file is retrieved as "myfile.zip".
   Content will be extracted in myFileDir directory */
```