# Nodejs download s3 images (getObject) in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download images from S3 bucket in a loop. My bucket is not public and using the direct getSignedURL doesn't work (Forbidden error). I need to download (between 10 - 30) images from S3 upon user selection from the user interface (and then later just delete after creating a GIF).

It downloads correct amount of images (with correct names) but the content of all the images is replaced with the last image on the local machine. I even wrote a Promise to call within the loop (hoping that each getObject call will complete first before going to the next) but didn't work. Except bluebird, I tried all solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39728772/3377101), but same result. My code looks like this:

```
var urlParams = {Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: ''};
  for (i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i+=increment) {
    urlParams.Key = imageNames[i]+'.jpg';
    pathToSave = '/local-files/'+urlParams.Key;

    var tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(pathToSave);
    // I tried a Promise (and setTimeout) here too but gives me the same result
    var stream = s3.getObject(urlParams).createReadStream().pipe(tempFile);
    var had_error = false;
    stream.on('error', function(err){
      had_error = true;
    });
    stream.on('close', function(){
      if (!had_error) {
        console.log("Image saved");        
      } 
    });    
  }
```

After the above code finishes, as I mentioned all images with correct names are saved but due to the non-blocking issue here, all images contain the content of last image in the array (imageNames). The Promise I wrote and tried is below

```
function getBucketObject(urlParams){
    return  new Promise ((resolve, reject)=> { 
      var pathToSave = '/local-files/'+params.Key;
      var tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(pathToSave);
      var stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(tempFile);
      var had_error = false;
      stream.on('error', function(err){
        had_error = true;
      });
      stream.on('close', function(){
        if (!had_error) {
          resolve(pathToSave);
        } 
      });
    })
}
```

Both setTimeout and Promise are not working for my issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Fix your authentication problem first.

Comment: I didn't add authentication code above but the authentication seems to work fine. I'm not sure which line (section) you referred to? I put everything (from inside the loop) in a separate function and then call that function itself in setTimeout, which seems to work, but doesn't seem to be a good solution. Any other (better) advice will be much helpful

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than that if you're getting a forbidden error, and you're sure your content exists, then you're not setting up your key/secret for auth correctly.

Comment: Oh I see sorry. The content exists for sure, I triple checked. I was trying to pass the images (from signedURL) to another plugin to read them and create GIFs, but it kept throwing Forbidden error. Then I added CORS configuration on aws but then I found out that the image read directly from aws using the plugin wasn't working (I didn't investigate much for that to be honest), then I decided to download the images first then delete them once the GIF is created

Comment: can you try by using `let` rather than `var`? specially `var pathToSave = '/local-files/'+params.Key;` Change it to `let pathToSave = '/local-files/'+params.Key;`

Comment: @Anshuman Jaiswal It worked :O I just changed them to let and also brought urlParams within the loop (with let) and now it saves images perfectly. What a stupid mistake that has got me stuck for "3" days. Thanks a lot. How can I up-vote your answer?

Comment: @Bilal just added answer, you can accept & upvote there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `let` instead of `var`

Modify your code as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i+=increment) {
    let urlParams = {Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: imageNames[i]+'.jpg'};
    let pathToSave = 'img/analysis/'+urlParams.Key;
    getBucketObject(urlParams).then(function(pathToSave){
      console.log("image saved");
    })
}

function getBucketObject(urlParams){
    return  new Promise ((resolve, reject)=> { 
      let pathToSave = '/local-files/'+params.Key;
      let tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(pathToSave);
      let stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(tempFile);
      let had_error = false;
      stream.on('error', function(err){
        had_error = true;
      });
      stream.on('close', function(){
        if (!had_error) {
          resolve(pathToSave);
        } 
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: OK thanks I just voted the solution but because of my reputation points, it only recorded but not displayed publicly

Answer (score 0):

Following what @Anshuman Jaiswal suggested in the comment, I tried the code with let instead of var and it works now. Thanks Anshuman. The code in the loop looks like below

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageNames.length; i+=increment) {
    let urlParams = {Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: imageNames[i]+'.jpg'};
    let pathToSave = '/local-files/'+urlParams.Key;
    getBucketObject(urlParams).then(function(pathToSave){
      console.log("image saved");
    })
  }
```

And the promise function is below

```
function getBucketObject(urlParams){
    return  new Promise ((resolve, reject)=> { 
      let pathToSave = '/local-files/'+params.Key;
      let tempFile = fs.createWriteStream(pathToSave);
      let stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(tempFile);
      let had_error = false;
      stream.on('error', function(err){
        had_error = true;
      });
      stream.on('close', function(){
        if (!had_error) {
          resolve(pathToSave);
        } 
      });
    })
}
```